# ASP.NET connection string to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

Well I was developing an ASP.NET webforms app in Visual Studio and it worked well. It has 2 SQL Server connection strings, one for ASP.NET Identity and the other for my own tables. Then I wanted to test my app on a real server. So I changed the connection strings to this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=WIN-9I87AF3QUO9;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AdManager-20141230074246;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="StracturesConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=WIN-9I87AF3QUO9;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AdManager-20141230074246;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now the `DefaultConnection` works well. but the second one doesn't.

I get an error:

> A network-realated or instance-specific error

here is the code of my DbContext

```
public class StructureDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StructureDbContext()
        : base("StructuresConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Structure> Structures { get; set; }

    public DbSet<StructureType> StructureTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

and this one is the db initializer:

```
    public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StructureDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(StructureDbContext context)
    {

        Structure s = new Structure();
        s.StructureTypeID = null;
        s.Description = "Test";
        s.CityID = 45;
        s.Address = "test";
        s.Price = 400;
        context.Structures.Add(s);

        StructureType t = new StructureType();
        t.Name = "بیلبورد";
        context.StructureTypes.Add(t);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If they are identical connection strings, then it is most likely your code calling the second connection string isn't referencing correctly. Can you share some code showing how the connection strings are used?

Comment: well I don't have the code right now. but I use entity framework code first and these connection strings are in web.config file.

Comment: One is called StracturesConnection. Did you call it StructuresConnection in your code? (first a -> u)

Comment: yes. as I said it works properly on localdb. the name of the connections are the same as when I was developing on visual studio.

Comment: How do you know the first one is working? Integrated Security usually does not work out of the box on a server.

Comment: Here is check list to fix this errror. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne/16257101#16257101

Comment: @HirenDhaduk I checked this list before. but everything was ok :(

Comment: @RobTillie I can login using Identity but I can't see the list of structures

Comment: Can you post the part of your code that uses this connection string?

Comment: Can you check one thing , Start sql server management studio and connect with WIN-9I87AF3QUO9 this as server name and select windows auth , press connect. Let us know what happens.

Comment: @RobTillie OK wait a few minutes and I'll post it.

Comment: @HirenDhaduk It connects without any problem. tables of Identity are created. but my tables are not.

Comment: I guess there is permission related issue. Can you connect to that server using sa?

Comment: well, is it possible to have a permission related issue and one of the two connection strings work? because both of them are the same and one of them works but the other doesn't.

Comment: Try a solution-wide search for hard-coded connection strings as noted in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849514/772086). It's possible your old connection string is ghosting on you.

Comment: @Mike well I'll look for it. I've added some code to my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is a miss spelling. in the connection string I wrote "Stractures" and this is wrong! sorry for wasting your time. I should go and check why this works on visual studio!